# PHP foreach that returns keys only

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Theoretical question that perhaps does not make any sense but still, maybe there is a clever answer.

I want to iterate through array and get its keys and to something with them. A quick example of what I do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $other_array[$key] = 'something';
}
```

Now, `PHP Mess Detector` screams that `$value` is unused in this scope. Therefore I was thinking that perhaps this is not the best way to access `keys` of my `array`.

Any idea how to do it without unnecessarily taking out `values` out of my `array`? Does it have any significant performance impact ... or perhaps I am just being paranoid and should carry on without wasting anyone's time with stupid questions :).

Comment: It's normal. But U may use this: $keys = array_key ($array);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $other_array[$key] = 'something';
}

Comment: You can suppress mess detector's warnings for instances like these: 
http://phpmd.org/documentation/suppress-warnings.html

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
 // do your stuff
}
```

That would make the *foreach* iterate over an array consisting of the keys from your array instead of the actual array. Note that it's probably not better from a performance standpoint though.

Comment: I believe array_keys() would be called for each iteration here, so it's probably not the smartest move?

Comment: No from what I remember the array that goes into the foreach if evaluated once. Just like doing *foreach(array("a", "b", "c") as $letters)* does not create a new array on every iteration. If that's incorrect then sure, create a $keys variable before the foreach... Do you have any reference pointing to the fact that foreach evaluates the array on each iteration?

Comment: From what I can see foreach() is implemented using iterators and thus only calls the function that returns an array once. Then it uses the iterator which points to the existing result set to continue with each item. So it's perfectly safe to to *foreach(array_keys() ...*

Comment: @inquam thank you for your insight! This came from my JavaScript experience, where doing `for (var i = 0; i < abc.indexOf('aa'); i++)` would call indexOf in each iteration. I guess my idea was that all languages would do it the same way - and I'm glad they don't!

Comment: I did some testing and `foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key)` is about 50% to 60% slower than `foreach($arr as $key => $val)`. But it is right, that there is no difference where you put the `array_keys($arr)`. (tested with an array of 255 elements and 100000 round with php 5.6.0)

Comment: @AbcAeffchen: Makes sense because it should essentially have to traverse two arrays by using `foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key`, once for traversing the array and building the new array of keys and then once to traverse that array instead of iterating the primary array once and reading both values and keys from it right away.

Comment: @inquam Thanks for verifing this performance issue. I added an answer to show how to fix the phpmd issue instead of corrupt the code to satisfy phpmd. Nevertheless +1 for pointing out the possibility for a performance issue ;)

Comment: @Zathrus Writer of course abc.indexOf is evaluated on each loop iteration, since it is in the test to be evaluated if the for loop should be exited.  I suspect that if it were in the initialization such as var i = abc.indexOf('aa') it would only be evaluated once (but have not tested this).

Comment: @Jeff That is how it is in most other languages, like C++ etc. I remember testing this years ago in PHP and back then it acted the same. The initialization is done once, but a function call in the conditional part of the for loop would have to be called on each iteration since the return value could change. Ofc, if the return value is static and this can be deduced by the compiler/interpreter this will be optimized on most modern languages and not actually do each function call.

Answer (score 19):

Just ignore this message.

In PHP the way you used `foreach` is the fastest. It is right, that you should avoid unused variables, but in this case you cannot avoid it, without losing some performance.

E.g. `foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key)` is about 50% to 60% slower
 than `foreach($arr as $key => $notUsed)`.

This issue of phpmd is already reported [here](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/issues/48) and there is also already a pull request [here](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/pull/198).

Until phpmd is updated you can also use [this little hack](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/issues/48#issuecomment-58123855)

In the file `/src/main/php/PHPMD/Rule/UnusedLocalVariable.php` in the method `collectVariables(..)` (line 123 in my case) replace

```
if ($this->isLocal($variable))
```

by

```
if ($this->isLocal($variable) && !($this->isChildOf($variable, 'ForeachStatement') && $variable->getName() === '$notUsed'))
```

This will stop phpmd from reporting `$notUsed` *anywhere* inside a foreach loops.

**UPDATE:**
The recommendation above assumes PHP 5.6 (the relevant version at the time of writing this answer). But time went by and now using PHP 7.2 it seems to be the other way around. As always it depends on the exact use case, but for associative arrays with less than 100.000 keys it is faster to store `array_keys($arr)` in a variable and use this in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 5):

It's valid PHP code, don't fix the code, but fix PHP MD.
There is a config in [PHP MD 2.2](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/pull/198) 
And needs this rule:

```
<properties>
    <property
        name="allow-unused-foreach-variables"
        description="Allow unused variables in foreach language constructs."
        value="false" />
</properties>
```

Comment: Uh, where to put those lines??

Comment: @OlleHärstedt In the config file you are using, like ruleset.xml and then `phpmd codebase/ some_output_format rulesets.xml`

Comment: There's an answer below that provides context. If anyone else wonders.

Answer (score 2):

Hack by 18C :-)

In construction `as $key=>$value`, the $value is first assigned in PHP before assigning $key.

```
$array=[1,3,6,10];

foreach($array as $k => $k) 
   print($k.'<br/>');
```

For your code:

```
foreach($array as $key => $key) 
{
    $other_array[$key] = 'something';
}
```

Btw. do not use: `foreach($array as $k => &$k)`. It can disrupt your array.

Comment: You depend on an internal behavior. This could end bad.

Comment: @finder2 I agree. They can change this behavior in future versions and the bug will be hard to track. I'd consider `foreach ($array as $key => $_)`

Comment: @RoboRobok Later versions should be compatible with previous versions. If not, it's time to replace PHP with a better model. The same can be said about CSS hacks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an XML ruleset:

```xml
    <rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml/UnusedLocalVariable">
        <properties>
            <property name="allow-unused-foreach-variables" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set all keys to certain value you can just do it this way:

```
$array = array(
        'foo'=> 'oldval1',
        'bar'=> 'oldval2',
        'baz'=> 'oldval3'
);

$other_array = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), 'something');
print_r($other_array);
```

This will produce:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => something
    [bar] => something
    [baz] => something
)
```

Comment: +1 for the idea although that was not what I had in mind - example was oversimplified :). Thanks anyway - learning something new :)

Answer (score 1):

loop to avoid a foreach in a while.

```
$a = ['1','A','B','12','ui'];

 while(true) { sleep(1);
    $b = next($a) ? current($a): reset($a);
    echo key($a) , ':' , $b , PHP_EOL;
 }
```

Comment: ```while(3)``` is shorter. :-) Additionally you should avoid potentially infinite loops.