# How to use foreach while only defining the key

Tags: php, eclipse

So I have this slightly annoying issue: say I have a foreach loop like this:

```html
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
        do_something($key);
    }
```

In my eclipse environment, I have turned on the feature that displays warnings for unused variables, which is really helpful. However, it complains for all such occurences, where the `$value` is not used in the loop.

I was wondering if there is some syntax where I don't use this, like is available for `list()` :

```html
list(,,$my_var) = some_func();
```

//these returns an array with 3 elements, but I only need the last one

Note: The obvious would be to use `array_keys()`, but I don't want a function call; I'm merely asking if there's a shorthand I don't know of, or something like it. This is why the question [PHP foreach that returns keys only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346876/php-foreach-that-returns-keys-only) does not cover what I'm asking.

Comment: Hm... [PHP foreach that returns keys only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346876/php-foreach-that-returns-keys-only). You mentioned that you don't want a function call, I don't think it's possible. Why can't you leave the `value` there?

Comment: No, there is no way to do this without using a function.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the last element? If so, http://php.net/end

Comment: Check out the settings of the feature you mentioned; it might have something like `allow-unused-foreach-variables` in [PHPMD](http://phpmd.org/rules/unusedcode.html). Otherwise, there's [no sugar](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/issues/48).

Comment: @FirstOne, yes that is the exact same question (and I have the exact same problem, the editor complaining for `$value` being unused), thank you for this. However, I was looking for a solution without array_keys() or a function call whatsoever.

Comment: @raina77ow These are useful links, I'll explore that possiblity

Comment: I **REALLY** don't think this should be used, but just for testing I changed to `foreach ($arr as $key => $key) {` and `$key` has the key, not the value. Using it like this, can you just test if it still shows the `unused variables` warning?

Comment: @FirstOne that is an awesome idea which of course should never be used :) Still, I'd mark this as correct answer if you post it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TBH, I couldn't find any resource to back this answer, it works fine as far as my tests went, BUT **I CAN'T SAY FOR SURE WHETHER THIS IS OR ISN'T RECOMMENDED TO USE**.* (Probably not)

Here is what I came up with:

```
$arr = array('kN1' => '50', 'kN2' => 400);
//$arr = array('50', 400);
foreach ($arr as $var => $var) { // use same variable for both key and value
    print_r($var);
    echo '<br>';
}
// kN1
// kN2
```

[Run Viper](http://viper-7.com/xRqTaw)

Comment: Be careful: this behavior may change and not be valid in a future release of PHP. Also, this is an excellent way to introduce errors in your script if you later need to work on the key AND the value.

Comment: @Jocelyn Since the question is related to `unused variables`, I thought that the `value` wasn't needed, because if it was, the variable would be used, not showing the warning. Anyway, I'm with you! I said in the comments, I don't think this should be used ^^.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warning without introducing too much overhead just unset the unused variable once the loop is done.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$val) { 
    print_r($key);
}
unset($val);
```

BTW: I believe one should use a reference to the unused variable (`&$val` instead of `$val`). Otherwise you might end up producing a full copy of the variable with each iteration and that might be a costly operation.